# Unable to populate the RShiny Server with Shiny Apps

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, digital-ocean

I created a RShiny Server on an Ubuntu Machine. I followed all the instructions mentioned in [this](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#sign-up) link. When I try to load the app it gives me the error shown in the picture below.
[image]

I inspected the log file and it contains the following messages:

```
su: ignoring --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive with --login

Attaching package: â€˜shinyalertâ€™

The following object is masked from â€˜package:shinyâ€™:

    runExample


Attaching package: â€˜shinydashboardâ€™

The following object is masked from â€˜package:graphicsâ€™:

    box


Attaching package: â€˜shinyBSâ€™

The following object is masked from â€˜package:shinyalertâ€™:

    closeAlert

WARNING: the 'dashboardthemes' package is no longer being maintained as of version 1.1.6, and will eventually be removed from CRAN. It is recommended that users switch over to the 'bslib' or 'fresh' theming packages available on CRAN.

Attaching package: â€˜dplyrâ€™

The following objects are masked from â€˜package:statsâ€™:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from â€˜package:baseâ€™:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

â”€â”€ Attaching packages â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€ tidyverse 1.3.1 â”€â”€
âœ” ggplot2 3.3.6     âœ” purrr   0.3.4
âœ” tibble  3.1.7     âœ” stringr 1.4.0
âœ” tidyr   1.2.0     âœ” forcats 0.5.1
âœ” readr   2.1.2     
â”€â”€ Conflicts â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â”€ tidyverse_conflicts() â”€â”€
âœ– dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
âœ– dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

Attaching package: â€˜lubridateâ€™

The following objects are masked from â€˜package:baseâ€™:

    date, intersect, setdiff, union

Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
  method            from
  as.zoo.data.frame zoo 

Attaching package: â€˜scalesâ€™

The following object is masked from â€˜package:purrrâ€™:

    discard

The following object is masked from â€˜package:readrâ€™:

    col_factor

Killed
```

I am unable to understand what's causing the error and how to resolve it as I am very new to Ubuntu OS.

Comment: The word `Killed` indicates that most likely you are out of memory. You have the label `digital-ocean`, so I assume you created an instance on their server. When you are trying to use memory more than your limit, protection mechanisms on these servers usually kill you program. Try with a higher memory limit.

Comment: You were right. I just upgraded the instance and it worked. Thanks for your help!